# Trying to use IPipelineBehavior with ASP.NET Core - get System.InvalidCastException

Tags: mediatr

I'm using Mediatr 3's new features for Pipeline Behaviors.  Problem is, when I wire them into Mediatr, exceptions (System.InvalidCastException) get thrown for every `.Send()` call.  Handlers get called fine, but when its time for the pipeline behaviors to get called, it fails.

Here's my setup:

```
    services.AddScoped<SingleInstanceFactory>(p => t => p.GetRequiredService(t));
    services.AddScoped<MultiInstanceFactory>(p => t => GetRequiredServices(p,t));
    services.AddScoped(typeof( IPipelineBehavior<, >), typeof(AddSessionBehavior<, >));
    services.AddMediatR();
```

And my Behavior:

```
public class AddSessionBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor Accessor;
        public AddSessionBehavior(IHttpContextAccessor anAccessor)
        {
            this.Accessor = anAccessor;
        }
        public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
        {

            var response = await next();
            return response;

        }
    }
```

When I send my first message through mediator, I get:

```
System.InvalidCastException occurred
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Object cannot be stored in an array of this type.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at System.Array.InternalSetValue(Void* target, Object value)
   at System.Array.SetValue(Object value, Int32[] indices)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitClosedIEnumerable(ClosedIEnumerableCallSite closedIEnumerableCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at MediatR.ServiceCollectionExtensions.GetRequiredServices(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerImpl`2.GetPipeline(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 invokeHandler, MultiInstanceFactory factory)
   at MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerImpl`2.Handle(IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, SingleInstanceFactory singleFactory, MultiInstanceFactory multiFactory)
   at MediatR.Mediator.Send[TResponse](IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Merlin.Web.Controllers.CourseController.Add(CourseAddVM model)
```

If I comment out the wiring for my behavior, my handlers get called fine.  And the rest of the application seems to work.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Turns out that somewhere along the way an internal class with the same name as my behavior was created in a different namespace in my application.  Probably the result of a "Generate Class definition".

Removing the generated class cleared up the issue.